# How to setup my own XML API server?

Tags: php, xml, api

I run a LAMP based web server, and it would be useful to have an API.

Basically I need a script that can receive requests by GET or POST, authenticate against a list of auth users, run a mysql query and return results in XML.

Before reinventing the wheel by starting such script from scratch, I was wondering if there is a PHP class or base script I could use as starting point.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally recommend you use [slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), It's a very lightweight but thorough framework which would help you achieve what you need. It integrates into any script and easily supports authentication through the [slim-extras](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras) auth middleware.